# how to register onclick event to @Html.RadioButtonForSelectList in asp.net mvc 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My Model

```
 public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TestRadioList { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select an option for TestRadio")]
    public String TestRadio { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select an option for TestRadio2")]
    public String TestRadio2 { get; set; }
}

public class aTest
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<aTest> list = new List<aTest>();
        list.Add(new aTest() { ID = 1, Name = "Yes" });
        list.Add(new aTest() { ID = 2, Name = "No" });
        list.Add(new aTest() { ID = 3, Name = "Not applicable" });
        list.Add(new aTest() { ID = 3, Name = "Muttu" });
        SelectList sl = new SelectList(list, "ID", "Name");
        var model = new IndexViewModel();
        model.TestRadioList = sl;
        return View(model);
    }
```

My View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
 <div>
    @Html.RadioButtonForSelectList(m => m.TestRadio, Model.TestRadioList)
</div>
```

}

Helper method

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForSelectList<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listOfValues)
    {
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (listOfValues != null)
        {
            // Create a radio button for each item in the list
            foreach (SelectListItem item in listOfValues)
            {
                // Generate an id to be given to the radio button field
                var id = string.Format("{0}_{1}", metaData.PropertyName, item.Value);

                // Create and populate a radio button using the existing html helpers
                var label = htmlHelper.Label(id, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text));
                var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, new { id = id }).ToHtmlString();

                // Create the html string that will be returned to the client
                // e.g. <input data-val="true" data-val-required="You must select an option" id="TestRadio_1" name="TestRadio" type="radio" value="1" /><label for="TestRadio_1">Line1</label>
                sb.AppendFormat("<div class=\"RadioButton\">{0}{1}</div>", radio, label);
            }
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is the code i'm using... not sure how to give a onclick event for the control. In the helper method i could not find any appropriate htmlattributes parameter. as per my requirement. on click of any radiobutton in the list i need to call a js function with few parameters. which i'm not able to do. Someonce please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your helper come from here ? http://jonlanceley.blogspot.ch/2011/06/mvc3-radiobuttonlist-helper.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply Raphael. I'm not using the helper from  jonlanceley.blogspot.ch/2011/06/. i have edited my post with helper Method. Please have a look and let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got the means to test this at the moment, but a rough idea is adding IDictionary htmlAttributes to the method and passing it in there. If you dont have the required onClick code in the view, then you could omit the parameter and do it in the extension method

```
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForSelectList<TModel, TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listOfValues,
            IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            if (listOfValues != null)
            {
                // Create a radio button for each item in the list
                foreach (SelectListItem item in listOfValues)
                {
                    // Generate an id to be given to the radio button field
                    var id = string.Format("{0}_{1}", metaData.PropertyName, item.Value);

                    // Create and populate a radio button using the existing html helpers
                    var label = htmlHelper.Label(id, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text));

                    htmlAttributes["id"] = id;
                    var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString();

                    // Create the html string that will be returned to the client
                    // e.g. <input data-val="true" data-val-required="You must select an option" id="TestRadio_1" name="TestRadio" type="radio" value="1" /><label for="TestRadio_1">Line1</label>
                    sb.AppendFormat("<div class=\"RadioButton\">{0}{1}</div>", radio, label);
                }
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and then call it using something like:

```
@Html.RadioButtonForSelectList(m => m.TestRadio, Model.TestRadioList, new { onclick="someFunction();" })
```

alternatively you could set a css class and bind to the click event. for example,

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $('.someClassName').click( function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
</script>

@Html.RadioButtonForSelectList(m => m.TestRadio, Model.TestRadioList, new { @class="someClassName" })
```

Comment: Hi Phil, liked your question and bounty, so I stalked you a little and +1d your great answers and help to others.